# Windows Authentication occurs automatically with machine name, but not with '.com' domain

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I am trying to get a better understanding of what is going on with Windows Auth in our ASP.NET MVC 4 application.

It's just using standard Windows auth, and when I access the application via the machine name, from a workstation on the domain:

```
http://product/
```

Then authentication occurs automatically, and I am allowed through.
However, if I access the SAME machine, using a host-name that has been mapped in our DNS (to the exact same internal IP):

```
http://product.company.com
```

then I am presented with the basic authentication box for my Windows credentials. I can type them in and proceed, but I want to know - why am I being prompted to enter my credentials in the former, but not the latter, and how would I correct this?

[EDIT]
Here are some results of NSLOOKUP

```
C:\Users\me>nslookup
Default Server:  dnsserver.company.com
Address:  192.168.4.250

> product.company.com
Server:  dnsserver.company.com
Address:  192.168.4.250

Name:    producttest.company.com
Address:  192.168.5.106
Aliases:  product.company.com

> product
Server:  dnsserver.company.com
Address:  192.168.4.250

Name:    producttest.company.com
Address:  192.168.5.106
Aliases:  product.company.com
```

Comment: This is a security feature of browsers, not sending user information over the internet.  Browser sees you going to a domain, and doesn't send that information.  I think there are workarounds out there for this, but I'm not 100% sure as I've never had to deal with it.

Comment: @Gromer - thanks, but that doesn't make sense to me - I ran nslookup and my queries got the EXACT same results (see my edit) - so I dont see that the 'internet' is involved at all. Ever.

Comment: nslookup isn't your browser. I said it was what the browser thinks. And here's some more information on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491444/integrated-windows-authentication

Answer (score 1):

Just add your site to the local intranet zone in browser options.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor - can you explain what it is that makes the browser think that my site is NOT on the intranet in the first place? I wouldn't expect it would just be doing a dumb 'does it end with .com' test...

Comment: I believe that a dot (.) in the host name make it belong to the internet zone by default. You have to manually assign the site to the intranet zone then.